# When I scroll UICollectionView (paging enabled) too fast, it scrolls two pages

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

my qustion is simple.I have searched a lot and i'm familiar with UICollectionView but never saw this behavior of UICollectionView. please don't answer quickly and please read all my question.
I'm working on a project that uses collectionView (and auto layout). my collectionView is paging enabled and is working fine. but when I scroll it too fast (I mean very too fast) it scrolls two pages and shows the contents for next next row (previous previous row). also this code :

```
decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
```

didn't work.
I created a temp project that have 1 controller and a simple collectionView (that is paging enabled and the cells's size are same as the viewController size). and there is just a label in the cell. the lable number is same as the collectionView row. also set this:

```
decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
```

when I scroll it very fast from 1 to 2, it stops on 3 or vice versa.
this is my temp project code (that is auto layout):

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        collectionViewLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        collectionViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        collectionViewLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.horizontal



        self.collView.collectionViewLayout = collectionViewLayout

        self.collView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
    }


    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollCell
        print("cell For Item At Row \(indexPath.row)")
        cell.lblNumber.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: collectionView.frame.size.height)
    }
```

anybody knows what should I do? is it a normal behavior for UICollectionView?

Comment: Try this line `collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize = collectionView.frame.size`

Comment: @Jože Ws. No it didn't work.

Comment: Does `collView` uses auto layout?

Comment: @Jože Ws. Yes. updated my question. (added using auto layout)

Comment: @Jože Ws. you can create a sample project for yourself and test on it. its very easy

Comment: add this line `collectionViewLayout.itemSize = collectionView.frame.size` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145464/discussion-between-amin-akbarzade-and-joze-ws).

Comment: I think found the solution. I think it's a normal behavior for UICollectionView. if you scroll (very fast scroll) the photos in photo app (that is apple built in app for ios) while photos are full screen, you will see that 2 pages scrolls. hehe it's funny.